# Does a public key ensure that it only refers to a unique private key?

Tags: .net, assemblies, signing, strongname

When I crate a strong name and when sign an assembly with that, I know that private key is not available but the public key.

I just want to be sure that I get it correct:

- Does the Public Key only refers to a unique private key?
- Can I say it also for the public key token?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unique in the one-in-millions-of-quadrillions sense, yes. For a well-designed PKI system, keys are effectively unique.

Comment: So it means, when I refernce a strongly named assembly, in my assembly's manifest, storıng the public key is enough bcoz it always(!) points to a specific private key that pairs with this public key. Right?